# ngif not working with ViewData

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am having more trouble than I should with a simple variable condition check but I am new to Angular and was hoping that someone can help me out.  I am trying to set a bool in my controller and then check it in my View. Sounds easy and I am probably doing something small wrong(hopefully).

Here is the controller setting the variable:

```
        var admin = false;
        //do something that makes it true
        ViewData["Admin"] = admin;
```

Here is me trying to access the variable in the view and currently it acts as if it is not even considering the boolean value and showing my grids regardless.

```
@{ 
   bool admin = (bool)ViewData["Admin"];
 }
 <div ngIf="admin">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"
                 ui-grid-pagination
                 ui-grid-selection
                 ui-grid-edit
                 ui-grid-row-edit
                 ui-grid-validate
                 ui-grid-exporter
                 ui-grid-cellNav
                 style="height: 500px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" onclick="@(" window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Home", "Widgets", null) + "' ");" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-2">
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-2">Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And it just shows regardless of the condition and I wrote an output to the screen that confirms the value is True.  I have tried several different ways of syntax hoping I would be able to make it work but I am unable to find a way to get it to work.  Any help is appreciated my head is sore from banging it on the desk.  Thanks

Comment: change `ngIf` to `ng-if`

Comment: It's `ng-if` I suppose.

Comment: also, admin refers to a varaible within scope. Meaning, you should declare admin like this : `$scope.admin = false`, and assign it new values as such.

Comment: Did you define ng-app? See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_expression)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses.  @Jeroen Heier I did define ng-app and the grid is inside that div.  Also tried changing it to ng-if and it still didn't show either one.

Comment: It's almost as if it is refreshing so fast that the variable is cleared.  It blinks the grid for a millisecond then it disappears when I hit refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just cheated and used a if block instead and it worked for me

```
@{
   var admin = @ViewData["Admin"].ToString();
}
@if (admin == "True") {  //Show Grid }
```

I think it must be something with the value not being seen inside the div, just a guess.  Thanks Everyone for helping me there.

Comment: You are now using Razor. Casting to string is not needed. Your solution is even better because there is no unnecessary html being rendered.